# c# interop Word insert landscape page

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop, landscape

I´m trying to insert a landscape page into a Word document. But it changes all the pages to landscape. How can I insert only one landscape page in my word document?

My code:

```
object wdSectionBreakNextPage = 2;
        //object pageBreak = 7; //el 7 es el tipo. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdbreaktype?view=word-pia
        rngDoc.Select();
        //rngDoc.InsertBreak(pageBreak);
        rngDoc.InsertBreak(wdSectionBreakNextPage);
        rngDoc.PageSetup.Orientation = WdOrientation.wdOrientLandscape;
        rngDoc.PageSetup.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = 0;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph para = rngDoc.Paragraphs.Add();
        para.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inserting a section break is a good first step - that's required.

The problem is coming from this line, which *I assume* is directing Word to apply the page orientation to the entire document. (You don't actually specify what is assigned to `rngDoc`, but the behavior you describe indicates it's the entire document.)

```
rngDoc.PageSetup.Orientation = WdOrientation.wdOrientLandscape;
```

If it should be applied only to the new section then that section needs to be specified. Again, we have no idea what `rngDoc.Select()` is actually doing, since we have no context. In any case, performing a selection is irrelevant and the line is not needed. Something along these lines:

```
object objWdSectionBreakNextPage = 2; //Don't confuse with the actual enum name!
//get the index number of the section where rngDoc is located
int nrSections = rngDoc.Sections[1].Index; 
rngDoc.InsertBreak(objWdSectionBreakNextPage);
//set rngDoc to the new section
rngDoc = Doc.Sections[nrSections + 1].Range;
rngDoc.PageSetup.Orientation = WdOrientation.wdOrientLandscape;
rngDoc.PageSetup.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = 0;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph para = rngDoc.Paragraphs.Add();
para.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
```

Comment: @cindy-mesiter First of all, sorry for my awful english and thank u for helping. You are right, rngDoc.Select() is entire document.